# How to deploy hyperledger fabric on a network and run hyperledger composer on it?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm still a beginner and am working on a project. I have done the [getting started](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#prerequisites-and-setup) from the fabric docs but I don't know how exactly I am supposed to deploy it to a network so that it runs on multiple peers.
After creating the fabric, I want to deploy a hyperledger composer model on it. I've completed [the dev guide](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html) from the composer docs. So, I wanted to ask whether the process would be any different from deploying to a fabric with a single peer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the Composer Developer Tutorial:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html

The you have installed a Fabric (currently at v0.8), created a Composer business network definition and deployed it to a channel on your Fabric development instance.

The process from a **development** perspective is identical, regardless of how many peers you have.

Comment: Link is broken :(